# File name does not match module name

Tags: windows, haskell, visual-studio-code, haskell-stack, haskero

Newbie playing with [haskell stack scripting](https://haskell-lang.org/tutorial/stack-script) and [turtle](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.5.7/docs/Turtle-Tutorial.html).

- Created a folder `stack-scripts`. Thought if it looks good, then I'll create some haskell utils for me to replace bash scripts.
- Created a file named `turtle.hs` with following text:

  ```hs
  #!/usr/bin/env stack
  -- stack --resolver lts-11.2 script

  {-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

  import Turtle

  main = echo "Hello!"
  ```
- made the `chmod +x turtle.hs` and tried to execute it.
- Got the following error message:

  ```
  turtle.hs:1:1: error:
      File name does not match module name:
      Saw: `Main'
      Expected: `Turtle'
    |
  1 | #!/usr/bin/env stack
    | ^
  ```

It does what it should if I rename `turtle.hs` to `turtle.sh`. But then I have no syntax highlighting for haskell.

Also it works if I rename it to `something-other.hs`. But then Haskero (VSCode) complains about `import Turtle` line: `Couldn't guess that module name. Does it exist?`

What I'm missing here? Running in git bash on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you need to give the script a different name as the module name in which the code runs, will automatically be derived from it and now it will conflict with the imported `Turtle` module. Renaming it to `turtlescript.hs` and then

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-11.2 script --package turtle

{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Turtle

main :: IO ()
main = echo "Hello!"
```

worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, works for me too! Not sure about last part - `Haskero` highlighting an error on `import`. Should I do install turtle somehow or is it pure `Haskero` issue not working correctly in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure if stack scripts are supported in various IDEs. In intero (Emacs) I also get a red curly. If you want proper IDE support you might want to use a proper stack / cabal project.